# How to convert a negative to non-negative in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is rather a general question.

Actually I have a value `x=-77` (dBm) and I want to change it to dB so the command would be `y=pow2db(x)`. The problem is it does not accept negative values. So how do I change this to non-negative and then calcuate `y`?

Your comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: abs()? it returns the absolute value...

Comment: y=pow2db(x) is nothing but log of x for base 10 ,logrithm of negative values undefined.you are confused check again what is x and y

Comment: pow2db is not going to convert from dBm to dB! I highly doubt you want to just change it +77

Comment: the formula to calculate x(rssi_dBm)=-(33+agcval*(89-33)/(29-1)) where agcval=25(just an e.g) so this "x" gives me a negative value.So I want to change this to positive value.
                  PS The reason is because I am trying to plot these values which are suppose to increase but it decreases due to x(rssi_dBm).When we had a discussion it was said that it is because it is in "Pathloss dBm" so it is decreasing when the distance is decreasing.So I need to convert this to "pathloss dB" which will increase with respect to distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`abs()`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) function Matlab provides.

example:

```
abs([-2 2])
ans=
   2  2
```

Still check what you are doing. Logarithms work in a special way, and you may not be wanting the logarithm of the absolute... just check :D

Comment: @Shai  are you aware of how it works with logarithms ?

Comment: are you aware of how it works with logarithms ?

Comment: The problem is the concept, you may not want to do that by concept, it may not be the correct thing to do @VinithpNair .

Comment: i guess this one works perfectly. I even checked it via calculator (i.e.) x=-77
       abs(x)=77
       pow2db(x)=18.8...

while in calculator 10log(77) is also the same value .

Comment: @VinithpNair yeah, people is not triying to say that the math is wrong, but it is wrong to do it. So if there are 30 apples in the table log(e^10+20)=4.34333897889, but  you are not counting corectly the apples. STill you may be doing correctly, it was just an advice!

Comment: right ! now I get it !! understood !!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess one of these two possibilities:

```
y = pow2db(abs(x))
```

or

```
y = pow2db(abs(x)) *sign(x)
```

Not sure whether either one of them would be meaningfull though.